# Activity act as REAL dialog

Tags: android, dialog, onresume

I have an activity, that has in manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

When I start it, it looks like an activity, but when I close it it fires the onResume on the activity that started it. A real dialog will not do it.
How can I avoid the onResume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't - it's an activity. You could add some state machine to the calling activity using onPause etc. but that could get messy.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Dialog instead. Using the method

```
setContentView(View view)
```

For "filling" it